# Download unknown file extension in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am downloading file with flutter_downloader package but I don't know the package name of the file. The file downloads but does not have a name or extension. There is nothing about the file extension in the link and there are 2 types of file downloads. What should I do?

My code:

````
 if (hasGranted) {
   String tempDir = await AndroidPathProvider.downloadsPath;

   task.taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
     url: task.link!,
     savedDir: tempDir,
     showNotification:
         true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
     openFileFromNotification:
         true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
   );
 } else {
   setState(() {
     _checkPermission();
   });
 } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

enqueue has a parameter fileName: name of downloaded file.
If this parameter is not set, the plugin will try to extract a file name from HTTP headers response or `url`

Comment: Browsers do not ask for the file name and extension when downloading a file. This is ridiculous. What should I do?

Comment: flutter_downloader package is only for  android and ios

Comment: I mentioned traditional browsers or something. Manually entering the file extension and name is medieval